# Merge [blog], [blogs], and [blogging]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Currently:
[blog](/questions/tagged/blog) x 124
[blogs](/questions/tagged/blogs) x 235
[blogging](/questions/tagged/blogging) x 88

See my answer to choose whether to keep [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) or [blogs](/questions/tagged/blogs).

**It's been four months.. I think that's enough time to wait for feedback. Can a moderator please merge them?**

Comment: On which of the sites?

Comment: Stackoverflow. I forgot, sorry

Comment: @The Cat: Whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 1):

Also: 82 questions tagged `blogging` (most of which should probably just be closed).

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda peripheral, but I hand-sorted `[blog-software]` (1) into `[blog-engine]` (10), `[blogengine]` (4) into `[blogengine.net]` (29), and `[weblog]` (1) into `[blogs]` (226).

I also voted for `[blogs]` in the voting thing below.

Answer (score -4):

+1 if you think `blog` should be kept.

-1 if you think `blogs` should be kept.

(I can't vote my own post but I say `blog` is much better, even if it has less questions tagged as such)

Comment: Nice way to do a boolean vote

Comment: What if Pollyanna thinks that `blogs` should be kept?

Comment: lol counting me we're at 5 for `blog`, 5 for `blogs` :(

Comment: -1: Keep the popular one.